# Generating samples from $u(7,10)$

Tags: simulation, uniform-distribution

I have the following assignment:

It requires to generate samples from $u(7,10)$,the uniform distribution on the interval $2 \leq x \leq 11$. Compare the normalized histogram with the density function(pdf).

I have no idea. I need help please, thanks.

Comment: This is my early beginning on the study of simulation and I have to work on it,I beg help!

Comment: What software can you use?  Since we here have no ideas about that, why not ask the person giving the assignement for some help?

Comment: It requires us to use MAT LAB.I find it hard to use.

Comment: Yet another reason to talk in person to they one making the assignment!

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the uniform distribution on $[2,11]$ is denoted by $u(7,10)$, but anyway, the steps are:

1. Generate a long random vector with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$: for example, `rand(1000,1)` creates a column vector of size $1000$ with this distribution.
2. Apply the linear transformation that maps $[0,1]$ onto $[2,11]$
3. Create the histogram with some reasonable number of bins, maybe $30$.
4. Plot the constant function $\dfrac{1}{11-2}$ on the interval $[2,11]$: this is the pdf.

The result should look like this:

[image: histogram]

I used [Scilab](http://www.scilab.org) instead of Matlab; the syntax is identical in the computational part and slightly different in the graphic output part.

```
x = (11-2)*rand(1000,1)+2*ones(1000,1)
histplot(30,x) 
t = 2:0.01:11
f = (1/(11-2))*ones(t)
plot(t,f)
```